# Responsive facebook comment box

Tags: responsive-design, facebook-comments, fluid-layout

I've been researching several **different** ways to force a **facebook comment box** plug-in to be fluid/responsive/liquid/whatever-we-call-it *(just showing the stupidity of names)*, and all of them work fine. But also, all of them make the plug-in disappear when accessing from *Google Chrome*.

I'm using this:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments span, .fb-comments.fb_iframe_widget span iframe {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Which has the same results *(apparently)* as:

```
#fbcomments, .fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-comments span{
width: 100% !important;
 }
```

**Question**: How can I fix this strange behavior? *(Why does it happen?)*

Thanks for your time. Wether you do help me or not, have a nice to-day! :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

this worked for me: Add to the fb-comments div data-width="100%"

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/comments" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

and it will be responsive when you resize the browser.

you can put the fb-comments div inside another div and give that div the width you want.

Comment: This will definitely work as stated in Facebook Documentation:

`data-width`: The width of the plugin. Either a pixel value or the literal 100% for fluid width. The mobile version of the Comments plugin ignores the width parameter, and instead has a fluid width of 100%.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#settings

Comment: @Ja8zyjits now it is ;) - By the time it was asked, data-width was not available. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just Insert  data-width="100%" in the div

```html
<div class="fb-comments"  data-width="100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is facebook comment part-**

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/comments" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

**Just add this CSS bellow the div-**

```
<style>.fb_iframe_widget span[style]{width:100% !important;}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use data-mobile atribute

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/comments" data-numposts="5" data-mobile="true"></div>
```